# Array of 1's and 0's to hex

Tags: c, types

I have an array of 1's and 0's in *C*.

```
int foo[8];

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i; i < 8; i++)
  {
      foo[i] = 0;
  }

 foo[1] = 1;
 foo[3] = 1;
}
```

So, my array now is something like this:

**01010000**

And I want to convert this `bin` representation of my array to `hex` number.
In this case it will be **0x50**.

Is there any fast and easy way to do this?

Comment: Group 4 elements, compute the decimal value and look the corresponding digit in a lookup table.

Comment: @aglasser I am not asking for string, but for array

Comment: A string in C is represented as an array of characters terminated with a NULL byte. A string **is** an array.

Comment: @aglasser So, it is a good idea to convert int array to char array?

Comment: No, you don't need that conversion.

Comment: Converting from int to char is trivial, but I don't see how it is any different here. You can easily adapt the code given for an int array or a char array. Modify the `do...while` to another for loop that just increments i instead of incrementing the a pointer. int b = *a=='1'?1:0 is just assigning an int value to b whether *a (the current char) is a 1 or 0. Trivial to implement with ints. [Post in question is here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5307692/2599996)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Altering your question to add the solution is not how StackOverflow works. Please see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for the proper way to do so. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean a hex number? Print it out in hex, or a string of hex rep?

Comment: I think I'd be using `int value = 0; for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) value = (value << 1) | foo[i];` to get the integer corresponding to the binary digits.  This can then be formatted to `0x50` with `char hex[10]; snprintf(hex, sizeof(hex), "0x%.2X", value);` (or just use `printf("0x%.2X\n", value);`, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, for some adaptability?

```
int start = 0, size = 4, i, value = 0;
for (i=start;i<size+start;i++) {
    value *= 2;
    if (foo[i] == '1') {
        value ++;
    }
}
```

Simple modular arithmetic.  `value` is going to end up as 0-15, which you can easily convert to a hexadecimal character, and iterate the loop to collect as many hex digits as needed/available.